# Is there any way to create a globally accessible class without using 'static' or singleton?

Tags: c#

I have a class that I would like to have a globally accessible instance of. I would prefer to not make it static due to databinding issues that I've been having. I would also like to avoid the singleton pattern. I have tried using IOC Containers with static properties but these also have databinding issues.  So, is it possible to have global accessibility without the use of `static`? If so, how could I go about implementing such a solution?

Comment: "databinding issues"?

Comment: What kind of project is this, or is it a general concern?

Comment: What does your abhorrence of the singleton pattern stem from?  If you need a reusable class that should be globally accessible it seems like perhaps that would be your answer.

Comment: Why avoid the singleton pattern? It's a tried and true way to do what you're wanting to do.

Comment: Just curious, is there a reason why you don't want to use the singleton pattern in this instance?

Comment: Good question, but I'm with @DavidL. A singleton would relieve the issue and provide good unit-testability.

Comment: I've heard very mixed things about the singleton pattern. Some seem to like it, others say to avoid it.

Comment: @JasonD There are plenty of times you SHOULD avoid it.  However, this seems to be a great time to give it a shot.  "Globally Accessible" indicates that it should only be instantiated once.  That is what the Singleton pattern provides.  I highly suggest giving it a try and seeing if it solves your problems.

Comment: @JasonD Yes but it only applies to handmade singletons which tend to be error prone. If you have a singleton from an IoC/DI then you are most likely fine.

Comment: @JasonD: the use of the singleton pattern is a personal preference. Some believe that DI is the way to go but, IMHO, if that is the only reason, to have a globally accessible object for data-binding, then the singleton is a good option. That's not to say that as time progresses and you have more than 2 or 3 objects, you should avoid DI. There is a point where implementing a DI pattern becomes useful. But for only a few, I would simply use the singleton pattern to get off the ground and as development continues, convert to DI. Make sense?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I'll give the singleton pattern a shot here as well as looking into DI. Like I said, I was just wary of it due to some of the things I've read. To everybody who's posted here, I appreciate your help!

Comment: @IAbstract I have no idea where you get the idea that singletons assist testing from. Singletons are one of the biggest obstacles to good unit testing around, to the extent that they are justifiably seen as an anti-pattern by anyone serious about unit testing. Sure it's a personal preference; I just prefer to do things properly and so avoid singletons like the plague.

Comment: @DavidArno: I have no problems unit testing a singleton. It is a static object that presents problems with unit testing. My remark that *singletons assist unit testing* is in comparison to a static counterpart. That said, I do agree with your answer ;) +1

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I'd suggest that if you have a need for a globally accessible class, then there is likely something wrong with your design. You should seek to minimise the scope of all aspects of any application as that helps reduce coupling. SO if possible, you should consider restructuring your application to minimise the number of areas that are dependent on this class.

Next, you are right to identify singletons and static access as things to avoid, unless the item being access has no mutable state or side-effects. Your talk of "data binding issues" suggests it does have side effects, so you are on the right track here.

If you aren't going to use some sort of locator pattern (such as statics or singletons) then injecting the value throughout the aspects of your application that need access is the only way. You could look at using an IoC container here, though I've no idea if it would help in your case. Simply requiring an instance of your class in the constructors of you other classes results in a DI model, so IoC containers aren't needed to achieve a DI solution.

But I'll reinforce my first point: rather than seek a way to make the class globally accessible, seek to minimise the need for access to it throughout the code.

Answer (score 0):

yes. use dependecy injection.

windsor, Unity, simple injector etc.

tutorial: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921152.aspx
[Correctly use dependency injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573371/correctly-use-dependency-injection)

Comment: Op have "databinding issues"

Comment: Link only answers are generally considered bad practice, since if the link is taken down, the answer has nothing to stand upon in the future.

Comment: @DavidL Not to mention the fact that it's a zero-effort answer. It also doesn't actually answer the question as the poster here has redirected their inquiry rather than actually answering it. This would be best as a comment.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain how the OP would use DI to make something globally accessible, rather than listing a few IoC containers and providing a couple of vague links?